# QT GUI: QPrintDialog not opening when called

Tags: c++, qt

I have a problem with QPrintDialog. Its not opening when I call the function .exec();

Here is the code:

```
void MainWindow::on_action_Print_triggered(int b,const QString &arg1 )
{
    QString textFromField = ui->textEdit->toPlainText();
    QPrinter printer;
    QPrintDialog *printDialog = new QPrintDialog(&printer, this);
    printDialog->setWindowTitle("Print");
    printDialog->exec();
    if(printDialog->exec()==QDialog::Accepted)
    {
        QPainter painter;
        painter.begin(&printer);
        painter.setFont(QFont(arg1,b));
        painter.drawText(100, 100, 500, 500, Qt::AlignLeft | Qt::AlignTop, textFromField);
        painter.end();
    }
}
```

thanks for your help!!!

Comment: Note that you are invoking `printDialog->exec()` twice.

Comment: @skypjack isn't it supposed to open twice rather than not showing at all?

Comment: I'm not saying that's the root of his problem, I'm saying that it shouldn't be called twice that way. That's all. Not sure about how the dialog works internally, it could also be that `exec` called twice results in an error like that one, I don't know, never tried before...

Comment: @skypjack the weird thing about this function is that it has worked for me a year ago.

Comment: @skypjack I have tried commenting the if statement and it doesn't work.

Comment: Are you sure that `on_action_Print_triggered` is called ? Which Qt version are you using, on which OS ?

Comment: If you use the Qt automatic connection, the arguments of the function are not right (and it is probably `on_actionPrint_triggered` if you have created a menu in the ui Designer)

Comment: @Ilya I'm using Qt 5.1.1 on Windows 10.

Comment: @bibi can you explain to me what do I need to change.

Comment: @DomenJesenovec if you used the designer and created an action this is usaully called `actionPrint`, and if you rely on the atomatic connection of signals/slots your public slot should be called accordingly: `on_actionPrint_triggered` rather than `on_action_Print_triggered`

Comment: @bibi That is not the case. All of my functions are declared like that.

Comment: @bibi This function has no arguments. That was the problem. Thanks for your help!!!!

Comment: Great! would it be nice to write your own answer (stackoverflow encourages this!)

Answer (score 0):

The function must not have arguments. The corrected function:

```
void MainWindow::on_actionPrint_triggered()
{
    QString FONTH, a;
    int SIZEOFFONTH;
    a=ui->comboBox->currentText();
    SIZEOFFONTH=a.split(" ")[0].toInt();
    FONTH=ui->fontComboBox->currentText();
    ui->label->setText("Printing");
    QString textFromField = ui->textEdit->toPlainText();
    QPrinter printer;
    QPrintDialog *printDialog = new QPrintDialog(&printer, this);
    printDialog->setWindowTitle("Print");
    if(printDialog->exec()==QDialog::Accepted)
    {
        QPainter painter;
        painter.begin(&printer);
        painter.setFont(QFont(FONTH,SIZEOFFONTH));
        painter.drawText(100, 100, 500, 500, Qt::AlignLeft | Qt::AlignTop, textFromField);
        painter.end();
    }
}
```

Comment: Why you are calling printDialog->exec(); twice?

Comment: @demonplus For testing.